# How do you find the revision of a branch prior to a ‘svn copy trunk branch’ so I can revert the copy

Tags: svn

I was attempting create new branch, but accidentally copied our trunk to one of our existing branches.

I thought, no problem, I will just do a reverse merge / copy from the branch revision, just prior to my mistake.

But, when I go to look at the branch log to find the previous revision I have nothing but the trunk history and no history for the branch - its been replace by the trunk history.

The copy appears to have wiped out all of the branch history and now the branch is the same as the trunk.  I guess that makes sense to some degree as branches are ‘like’ directories (or so I have read), but this is SVN and you can never truly delete anything - right??

So how do I locate the revision just prior to my blunder to fix this?  Also, should I do a copy or a reverse merge?

The branch I destroyed was copied from our trunk branch many months ago.  The trunk is very different now, while the branch only had a few changes since it was created.

I am somewhat new to SVN so please go easy on me.

Thank, Sweating

Comment: Something probably deleted that branch. Just examine you `svn log`, and look at the last entry for the pre-existing branch, roll back to that on the branch. Take the `svn log` from the whole project to find out, not the log of what is now that branch.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know I could look at the log for the whole repository at once. I'll try it out.

Comment: For svn 1.8 `svn log ^ --search BRANCHNAME -l 2` (last commit is you copy, previous - last "real")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we are using SVN 1.6

Answer (score 0):

First, I needed to look at the **whole** log for the repository - not the trunk or branch - that was the first bit to the problem - many thanks to **Wrikken** for the hint.

```
    svn log -v svn:/stuff

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2285 | stupidme | 2014-01-16 10:43:32 -0800 (Thu, 16 Jan 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
A /branches/dev/1.7.0 (from /trunk:2284)
Re-creating 1.7.0 branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2284 | stupidme | 2014-01-16 10:40:31 -0800 (Thu, 16 Jan 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /branches/dev/1.7.0 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2283 | someoneelse | 2014-01-13 14:55:58 -0800 (Mon, 13 Jan 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/apps/handler.cpp
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2282 | someoneelse | 2014-01-13 14:45:15 -0800 (Mon, 13 Jan 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/dev/1.7.0/apps/someotherfile.cpp
```

Because of the Delete at 2284, when I was looking at the log from the branch level (svn log -v svn:/stuff/branches/1.7.0), I couldn't see 2284 or 2282, but due to the copy at 2285, I could see 2283 so I thought that was the rev I wanted.

I tried reverting to 2283 and it just made things worse.

Now that I know it was 2282, it  was easy to correct - but  you must specify the revision with @ and not the ‘-r’ option - I discovered this from some other post on stackoverflow:

```
    svn move svn:/stuff/branches/dev/1.7.0 svn:/stuff/branches/dev/1.7.0_busted
    svn copy svn:/stuff/branches/dev/1.7.0@2282  svn:/stuff/branches/dev/1.7.0
```